# Use JSONata to alpha sort keys in a JSON object

Tags: jsonata

I'll start off by saying I'm aware that, acording to [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs." Nonetheless, in the real world, sometimes it would be nice to view keys in alphabetical order.

Unsorted:

```
{"B":2,"A":1,"C":3}
```

Sorted:

```
{"A":1,"B":2,"C":3}
```

Is there a way to do this in JSONata? (I understand I can pre- or post-process the data outside JSONata, but am curious whether there's a way to do this via JSONata.)

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties)

Comment: Thanks for asking. No it doesn't. I'm referring specifically to sorting object keys via JSONata.

Comment: Question has been edited to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I have just written the following function:

```
$sortObjectAlphabetically := function($obj){
    (
        $keys := [$keys($obj)];
        $keys := $keys^(<$);
        $merge([$map($keys,function($e){
            (
                {
                    $e : $lookup($obj,$e)
                }
            )
        })]);
    )
};
```

I've done an example at this link: https://try.jsonata.org/RbJqQxO0i